# Why can't I set default parameters to a recursive binary search function?

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

I'm reading a book about Data Structs and algorithms in Python, and it contains an example of a binary search function and I realized something...the function takes 4 parameters, but the last two will always be the same, that is, low=0 and high=len(data). Why can't I just set them as default parameters?

The main problem here is that setting low=0 is fine, but high=len(data) will raise an error because obviously data list is being accessed before being assigned a value. So, is there a way for the function to get the low and high values itself so I don't have to pass them as args for the main call (as the recursions require them nonetheless)?

```
def binary_search(data, target, low, high):
    """If target is found in indicated portion of a list, returns True
    The search only considers the portion from data[low] to data[high] inclusive."""

    if low > high:
        return False
    else:
        mid = (low+high) //2

        if target == data[mid]:
            return True
        elif target < data[mid]:
            #recur on the portion left of the middle
            return binary_search(data, target, low, mid-1)
        else:
            #recur on the portion right of the middle
            return binary_search(data, target, mid+1, high)

arr = [k+1 for k in range(10000)]
binary_search(arr, 4590, 0, len(arr))
```

Comment: make low and high as global variable then :)

Comment: Usually I get around this by having a front-end function for client code, and then a recursive internal details function. But you can do it your way by default "high=None", and in code set "if high is None: high = len(data)"

Comment: `low` and `high` are *not* always the same value. You are changing them as you recurse into the function e.g. `return binary_search(data, target, low, mid-1)` and `return binary_search(data, target, mid+1, high)`.

Comment: Oh, I thought you wanted defaults so the initial call is simpler. I should have read more closely.

Comment: @TomDalton sorry I should have expressed myself better, the main call will have the same last two args 99% of the time, whereas the recursive calls are in fact different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it does make sense to set default parameter values here.

Since you got this from a book which is trying to teach you something about data structures, I guess they omitted that to make it easier to understand.

As you wrote, you cannot know what the default `high` should be, but you dont have to. Just use `None` instead - that is a good default here:

```
def binary_search(data, target, low=0, high=None):
    """If target is found in indicated portion of a list, returns True
    The search only considers the portion from data[low] to data[high] inclusive."""

    if high is None:
        high = len(data)

    # the rest remains the same
```

Comment: Works like a charm, this could be useful for other recursive problems as well. Thank you!